# Почему не работает emit?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3, vue-cli

Недавно начал изучать Vue и столкнулся с очень странной и непонятной для меня проблемой.
Я не спорю, что с точки зрения архитектурного подхода данный код может быть неправильный, но всё же я хочу понять логику.
У меня есть четыре компонента HelloWorld->ButtonsList->ButtonsPlus,ButtonsMinus
Нижи их код

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref } from 'vue'
import ButtonsList from './ButtonsList/ButtonsList.vue'
defineProps<{ msg: string }>()
const plusHandler = () => {
  count.value = count.value + 1
}
const minusHandler = () => {
  count.value = count.value - 1
}
const count = ref(0)
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>

  <div class="card">
    <p>count is {{ count }}</p>

  </div>

  
  <ButtonsList @update:plusEmit="plusHandler"  @update:minusEmit="minusHandler"  />
</template>

<style scoped>
.read-the-docs {
  color: #888;
}
</style>
```

---

```
<script setup>
import ButtonPlus from '../Buttons/ButtonPlus.vue'
import ButtonMinus from '../Buttons/ButtonMinus.vue'
</script>



<template>
  <ButtonPlus/>
  <ButtonMinus/>    
</template>
```

---

```
<script setup>
    const emit = defineEmits();
    const plus = () => {
        emit('update:plusEmit')
    }
</script>


<template>
    <button @click="plus" >
        +
    </button>
</template>
```

---

```
<script setup>
    const emit = defineEmits();
    const minus = () => {
        emit('update:minusEmit')
    }
</script>


<template>
    <button @click="minus" >
        -
    </button>
</template>
```

Почему если в компоненте ButtonsList у меня одна кнопка, то всё работает корректно, а если две, то вообще ничего не работает и как данный функционал нужно реализовывать (если не использовать передачу функций для изменения как в React)?
Использую vue3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас ButtonsPlus и ButtonMinus отправляют сообщение родителю. Родителем для них является ButtonsList. Но он не обрабатывает сообщения от дочерних компонентов и не передаёт сообщения своему родителю.

Родителем ButtonsList является HelloWorld. Он ожидает сообщения от дочернего компонента, но не получает их.

По-видимому, всё работало, когда промежуточного компонента не было, и сообщения от ButtonsPlus и ButtonMinus попадали к родителю.

Надо добавить передачу от промежучного компонента. Примерно так:

```
<script setup>
import ButtonPlus from '../Buttons/ButtonPlus.vue'
import ButtonMinus from '../Buttons/ButtonMinus.vue'
const emit = defineEmits();
</script>



<template>
  <ButtonPlus @update:plusEmit="emit('update:plusEmit')"/>
  <ButtonMinus @update:minusEmit="emit('update:minusEmit')"/>    
</template>
```

Comment: Вынужден не согласится, так как ранее вариант с одной кнопкой работал с наличием промежуточного компонента, но так или иначе, ваше решение сработало, спасибо большое!

Comment: Тогда отметьте его как принятое.